# Python openpyxl .xlsx if column is X print current row

Tags: python, excel, xlsx, openpyxl

I can't seem to figure this out.

I am trying to go through a whole column in a spreadsheet and return the row of data if value is found.

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Please supply what code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Please Import xlrd and run this code and modify as you

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('file.xls')
for s in workbook.sheets():
for r in range(s.nrows):
    for c in range(s.ncols):
        print "row::::: ", r
        print "column:: ", c
        print "value::: ", s.cell(r,c).value
```

Comment: Could use a little explanation on how this for loop would work.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing is simply to loop through all the rows of the worksheet, check the cell in the relevant column and break when you get the value.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename)
ws = wb[sheetname]
for row in ws:
    cell = row[0] # for column 'A'
    if cell.value == sentinel:
        break

# do what you want with the row
```